# How to reset the globalization resource provider to default resx provider

Tags: asp.net, globalization

I would like to reset my globalization provider for an inner section of my web site.

The site root uses a custom sql provider, I would like to use resx in my subfolder.

what should I set in resourceProviderFactoryType="???"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to set it to it's default value using:

```
<globalization resourceProviderFactoryType=""/>
```

Hope that helps.